# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert one of my C# path finding programs into JavaScript to display graphically on a HTML canvas. I have been stuck for days on an error it keeps throwing up.

The program is basically a grid which has a start tile, end tile, walkable tiles and obstacle tiles. The program aims to plot a path from the start to end tile using walkable tiles and avoiding obstacle tiles.

The error it throws up is triggered when I attempt to calculate a path, the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The line of code it triggers on is a check that looks at the tile below the active tile to see  if its viable and not an obstacle:

```
if (pathGrid[r + 1][c] >= walkableID && pathGrid[r + 1][c] != obstacleID)
```

It is part of this:

```
        for (var r = 0; r < gridHeight; r++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c < gridWidth; c++)
        {  
            if (pathGrid[r][c] == walkableID || pathGrid[r][c] == targetID)
            {
                // check that it is not last row
                if (r < gridHeight)
                {   
                    // check that below is walkable and not an obstacle 
                    /*error*/if (pathGrid[r + 1][c] >= walkableID && pathGrid[r + 1][c] != obstacleID)
                    {
                        pathGrid2[r][c] = (pathGrid[r + 1][c] += 1);
                        changeMade = true;
                    }
                }

                // check that it is not first row
                if (r > 0)
                {
                    // check that above is walkable and not an obstacle 
                    if (pathGrid[r - 1][c] >= walkableID && pathGrid[r - 1][c] != obstacleID)
                    {
                        pathGrid2[r][c] = (pathGrid[r - 1][c] += 1);
                        changeMade = true;
                    }
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

If I comment out the statement in which this error occurs, the checks for above, left and right of the active tile run fine with no errors. I cannot fathom as to why just this is throwing up an error.

I have ensured that all grids used are initialised beforehand and contain empty elements:

```
    var playerID = 0
    var targetID =  -2
    var walkableID = -1
    var obstacleID = -3

    var pathGrid = [[]];
    var pathGrid2 = [[]];
    var tempGrid = [[]];

    for (var r = 0; r < gridHeight; r++)
    {
    pathGrid[r] = [];
    pathGrid2[r] = [];
    tempGrid[r] = [];

            for (var c = 0; c < gridWidth; c++)
    {
        pathGrid[r][c] = 0;
        pathGrid2[r][c] = 0;
        tempGrid[r][c] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (r < gridHeight)` should be `if (r < gridHeight - 1)`.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, can't believe I overlooked that!